# Import a CAD file to Protege

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I have modeled an ontology in Protege. Now I need to instantiate the different data I have. For example, I have some CAD files. How can I link them to my ontology? Is there a special Protege plug-in for this?

Comment: I have tried to answer your question, but strictly speaking your question does not meet SO standards. I.e., you mention your ontology without providing any details about it. You want to instantiate data, but you do not give an indication of what you have tried.  Your question can be improved by following the SO guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Dispite this I have answered the question by making some assumption to try and give you some guidance. You may find reading [this book](https://www.poolparty.biz/the-knowledge-graph-cookbook/) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to this in Protege. However, your ontology could define a way in which this can be done. Since you do not give any detail regarding your ontology, I made some assumptions wrt your ontology:

1. It defines some artifacts for which designs can exist, i.e., a vehicle part, a component, a building etc.
2. A design is defined using a CADFile.

Here is a minimal ontology to achieve this:

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/mydesigns#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/mydesigns> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/mydesigns> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

:Artefact rdf:type owl:Class ;
          owl:disjointWith :Design .


:Design rdf:type owl:Class .

:hasDesign rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
           rdfs:domain :Artefact ;
           rdfs:range :Design .


:isDefinedByCADFile rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
                    rdfs:domain :Design ;
                    rdfs:range xsd:anyURI .
```

It states that we have `Artefacts` and `Designs`. An `Artefact` can have `Design`s and are defined by CAD files.

Example data we may have for this ontology is:

```
:superFastSportsCar rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                             :Artefact ;
                    :hasDesign :performanceFocussedFuelInjector ,
                               :superiorTransmissionDesign .
                               
:performanceFocussedFuelInjector rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                                          :Design ;
                                 :isDefinedByCADFile "file:/filelocationOfPerformanceFocussedFuelInjector"^^xsd:anyURI .

:superiorTransmissionDesign rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
                            :isDefinedByCADFile "file:/filelocationOfSuperiorTransmissionDesignCADFile"^^xsd:anyURI .

:economyVehicle rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                         :Artefact ;
                :hasDesign :fuelEfficientEngine .



:fuelEfficientEngine rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                              :Design ;
                     :isDefinedByCADFile "file:/locationOfFuelEfficientEngineCADfile"^^xsd:anyURI .
```

It defines 2 artefacts, `superFastSportsCar` and `economyVehicle`. `superFastSportsCar` has designs for `performanceFocussedFuelInjector` and `superiorTransmissionDesign`. For each of `performanceFocussedFuelInjector` and `superiorTransmissionDesign` repective CAD file locations are assigned. `economyVehicle` only has a design for a `fuelEfficientEngine`.